# cant't create file on alfresco 4.0.0(3979) using Opencmis 1.0

Tags: alfresco, opencmis

In my project I have to migrate file to alfresco.

I have finished to create the application(java) and try it on my local using alfresco 4.0.0(4003) and it works well.

But when I try to run it on server it fails.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: Length Required
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:487)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.post(AbstractAtomPubService.java:629)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.ObjectServiceImpl.createFolder(ObjectServiceImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.createFolder(SessionImpl.java:814)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createFolder(FolderImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createFolder(FolderImpl.java:479)
    at org.bappenas.cmis.alfresco.openCmisAlfresco.connect(openCmisAlfresco.java:394)
    at org.bappenas.cmis.alfresco.openCmisAlfresco.main(openCmisAlfresco.java:71)
```

The server used alfresco 4.0.0(3979).

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason why you haven't upgraded to one of the various newer Alfresco 4.0.x service packs? That would certainly seem to fix your issue

Comment: I agree with Gagravarr that you are using a very old release of Alfresco. With that said, please provide the code that is causing this exception, otherwise it may be hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: Yes. You're rights. But I can't do that, because my job is only migrate the file. i have no permission to update alfresco.

Comment: If You two have other way to fix it let me know. Thanks before.

Comment: Hi @JeffPotts I have downloaded alfresco 4.0c and test my application on my local, but I have no problem with it. Any suggest about what happen? Do you think different OS(Linux and window) will cause the problem?

Comment: Hi @Gagravarr I have downloaded alfresco 4.0c and test my application on my local, but I have no problem with it. Any suggest about what happen? Do you think different OS(Linux and window) will cause the problem?

Comment: I think the problem is you're running a really old version of Alfresco, which appears to have a bug, so you'll need to upgrade to something newer (to fix that bug and others!)

Comment: Yes they are. I can't upgrade it, because they have an IT support and they wont to upgrade it. I'm just freelancer, my job is migrate files to alfresco 4.0c(4.0.0(3979)). I've test it on my local and works well.